# Coding and encoding in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, utf-8, ascii

I have a file.json and I load in python in this way:

```
fd = open('originalfile.json' 'r', encoding='utf8')
```

Then I do some modifications and one more time I write a new file in this way

```
with open("newfile.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    outfile.write('[\n')
    for i in result:
        json.dump(i, outfile, indent=8)
        outfile.write(',\n')
    outfile.write(']')
```

But in my originalfile.json I have text in spanish for example "Baterías" and when I write newfile.json this happened "Bater\u00edas" How can I write in the normal way?

Comment: That is the normal way. If you want it to have un-escaped UTF-8, use ensure_ascii=False.

Comment: can you explain me how please?

Comment: json.dump(i, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=8)

Comment: It's all here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Also, why do you _care_ which one you have? According to the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/), the two are both representations of the exact same string. The standard libraries in JS, Python, etc., and most if not all popular third-party libraries for languages that don't have JSON built in, will treat them the same.

Comment: In fact, to the extent there's a difference, the `\u00ed` is better, because JSON (unless it's specifically RFC7159-compliant) only implies UTF-8, rather than actually requiring it. So, `\u00ed` will always mean `í`, but `í` in UTF-8 may be interpreted as, say, `Ã­` in CP1252.

Answer (score 0):

Just formalising the comment made by Javier as an answer to make it easier to find for others. You need to specify the `ensure_ascii` argument to `json.dump`:

```
with open("newfile.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    outfile.write('[\n')
    for i in result:
        json.dump(i, outfile, indent=8, ensure_ascii=False)
        outfile.write(',\n')
    outfile.write(']')
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump